# Rename "bounded rationality" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for questions on bounded rationality [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundedrationality), which goes by `boundedrationality`. Might we want to change this to `bounded-rationality`, given that it seems standard on SE (at least in my experience) to separate out words with a dash?

Comment: Why not just two words: bounded rationality?

Comment: @GuidoJorg a tag can't have spaces in it. Customarily, spaces are replaced by tags.

Answer (score 3):

[boundedrationality](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundedrationality) could be made a synonym of  [bounded-rationality](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounded-rationality). Or its use could just be replaced, if we're not expecting others to use the unhyphenated version in the future.

I see that only the unhyphenated version exists at present, and its existence prevents the creation of the hyphenated version. I think this may need a mod to fix it.

Comment: I would suggest the replacement, since iirc, the latter should show up as a suggestion after the tagger types a couple letters in the tag name anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for flagging this issue. I have created a tag synonym from `boundedrationality` into `bounded-rationality`. Now the auto-correct will direct people to use `bounded-rationality` and if someone does inadvertently try to use `boundedrationality` the system will automatically map it into `bounded-rationality`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest replacing it completely. Standard syntax would have the tag as `bounded-rationality`. The change would be harmless and would be more consistent with other tags.